# SQL Server DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, distinct

```
SELECT dbo.CLIENTREP.ref, dbo.REP2.ref
  FROM dbo.CLIENTREP 
  FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.REP2 ON (dbo.REP2.ref = dbo.CLIENTREP.ref)
    WHERE dbo.REP2.ref is null OR dbo.CLIENTREP.ref IS NULL;
```

How can I specify that only `DISTINCT`  `dbo.CLIENTREP.ref` and `dbo.REP2.ref` are returned?

Comment: yes, this question wasn't there yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

```
SELECT distinct dbo.CLIENTREP.ref, dbo.REP2.ref
FROM dbo.CLIENTREP 
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.REP2 ON (dbo.REP2.ref = dbo.CLIENTREP.ref)
WHERE dbo.REP2.ref is null OR dbo.CLIENTREP.ref IS NULL;
```